# Automatic View Update in MySql

Tags: mysql, view

Does the view get automatically updated when the underlying tables get updated in MySQL without querying?

To further elaborate - if I update the table then does the view get updated even if I don't run any query on the view?

Comment: How do you access the view if you don't query it?

Comment: he means that after updating some data, can we access that latest data from the `view`

Comment: @diEcho that's pretty much the concept of a view. MySQL does not (yet) have materialised views.

Answer (score 19):

Every time you execute a query on the view, it will fetch the data currently in tables  - included all committed transactions on it, but not those UPDATE or INSERT queries taht have still not been committed.

but of course, once you have got that data, it will not send it again. There are triggers for that, but still your database client has to query the view data out.

To clear up a bit more: View does not store (cache) the data, it is a logical structure and will always look into the underlying tables.

Comment: Is there any documentation about the read committed data only?

Answer (score 8):

A view is a stored query accessible as a virtual table and is composed of the result set of the query. 
Changing the data in a referenced tables alters the data shown in subsequent invocations of the view.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)

its a bit like this.....

If you ask me the time now I will tell you it is ten o'clock.

If you ask me 2 hours later I will tell you it is twelve o'clock.

Unless you ask me I will not keep telling you the time.

Comment: Brian asked if the view updates its data automatically in case the underlaying table gets updated, not vice versa.

Comment: I have added an analogy for you to hopefully clarify how it works.

Answer (score 4):

If you have created the view of certain table then there is automatic update in the data in the view as you change the data or insert new data in its respective table.

However if you want to add more columns in the database table and  update its respective view then the change is not automatic.

For that you can use 'SQLYog'. It is nice tool to work with views.

Answer (score 2):

generally VIEWS updated automatically.

From [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

> Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such
>   as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying
>   table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one
>   relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the
>   underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a
>   view nonupdatable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Views automatically update in MySQL; including, but not limited to:

- Changing table structures
- Insert/Update/Delete procedures on Tables
- Changing View structures using CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW

NOTE:  Changing a table's structure requires re-creating the View.