# Query: MySQL Table Join

Tags: php, mysql

I see this question has been asked and answered a few times but I am struggling with something else.

the database:

```
 - table1= "clients"  | Columns:  "customer_id","company_name"
 - table2= "devices"  | Columns:  "id","device_id"
```

I want to join+create a new table with the above information.

This is my query:

```
 CREATE TABLE test SELECT clients.customer_id, clients.company, 
 devices.id, devices.device_id FROM clients, sites WHERE 
 clients.customer_id = devices.id
```

The problem:

Once this new table is created and I add new entries to "clients" and "devices" the newly created table "test" does not "update" with the new information. If I run my query again, then it only shows the updated information.  I need it to automatically update.

I probably should mention that I am a complete noob and have almost no experience in mysql, but I'm trying to learn and I just cant figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) instead of a table. [Read more...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093881/automatic-view-update-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use Select to view the information that you need. Just like this:

`SELECT clients.customer_id, clients.company_name, 
 devices.id, devices.device_id FROM clients, devices WHERE 
 clients.customer_id = devices.id`

Comment: Not sure, i only added a comment.

Comment: Indeed hahah, your tag say's your using php to. So you can always display the results of my exemple query in your php page. is that a idea?